# How to start the map activity (google map api) of my android application from a specific location with a highest zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps

**Note -- Solved**

This is the function which is setting the center in my map , with GPS locations i want more highest precise level and zoom level , what changes i have to make ?

```
package cc.co.ratan.www;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Collegemap extends MapActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.collegemap);
    MapView view =(MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);

    view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 

    final MapController control = view.getController();

    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener listner = new LocationListener() {

        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            control.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)arg0.getLatitude(), (int)arg0.getLongitude()));
        }
    };
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listner);



}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

this is my code after i edited . (looked and made changes from your blog )

```
package cc.co.ratan.www;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class Collegemap extends MapActivity implements LocationListener{
private String provider;
GeoPoint myLocation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //String provider;


    setContentView(R.layout.collegemap);

    MapView mview =(MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);

    mview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    final MapController control = mview.getController();

             LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) 

            this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(manager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
     if (location != null)
            plotLocation(location);
        else
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    manager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500L, 250.0f, (LocationListener) this);

    provider = manager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    LocationListener listner = new LocationListener() {

        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(Collegemap.this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(Collegemap.this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            control.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)arg0.getLatitude(), (int)arg0.getLongitude()));
        }
    };
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listner);

    ;

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

double roundTwoDecimals(double d){
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
    }
public void plotLocation(Location location) {
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (roundTwoDecimals(location.getLatitude()) * 1E6),
            (int) (roundTwoDecimals(location.getLongitude()) * 1E6));
    myLocation = point;
    MapView mview =(MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);
    mview.getController().animateTo(point);
    mview.getController().setCenter(point);
    zoomToMyLocation();}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private void zoomToMyLocation() {
    if (myLocation != null) {
        MapView mview =(MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);
        mview.getController().setZoom(18);
        mview.getController().animateTo(myLocation);
    } 
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ratan -- I think some code is missing from your activity...
Check below code plotmylocation will center map to gps location & zoomtomylocation will zoom map to that location you can add any zoom level there instead of 18 but I think 20 will be max value.

```
public class MapDragActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener{
String pinadd="";
private MapView map=null;
private LocationManager locationManager;
GeoPoint myLocation;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);


    map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (location != null)
        plotLocation(location);
    else
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500L, 250.0f, this);

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (location != null)
        plotLocation(location);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);
}  

@Override
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
} 

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void plotLocation(Location location) {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (roundTwoDecimals(location.getLatitude()) * 1E6),
                (int) (roundTwoDecimals(location.getLongitude()) * 1E6));
        myLocation = point;
        map.getController().animateTo(point);
        map.getController().setCenter(point);
        zoomToMyLocation();
}

private void zoomToMyLocation() {
    if (myLocation != null) {
        map.getController().setZoom(18);
        map.getController().animateTo(myLocation);
    } 
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: @ratan -- From my code??
check 
http://androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/map-marker-dragging/

Comment: hmm... sir you explained everything , let me work out , i am implementing this in my mini project.

Comment: couldn't get connection factory client  .. is the error i am getting in DDMS , i have proper permission and proper APi key . then wat could be the reson.

Comment: @Ratan -- I also got that error but everything is working fine for me & I don't know why that error comes..

Comment: but , sir . on changing the geopoints from the emulator the coordinates are not changing inside the map activity :(

Comment: @Ratan -- for map try to test on device as many times emulator doesn't work ( had many issues already with map & emulator)

Comment: anyway , Sir ... its working on Real device thanks a million .:)

Comment: sir :) please vote up my question , and close it as its solved .